# Deleting a IP from blacklist iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I created a blacklist using ipset and iptables called "blacklist", now i would like to know how i edit "blacklist" to remove or add IP's.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, i found the solution after some fiddling around...

**ipset list** (for listing your blacklist entries)

**ipset del** (blacklist name) (IP you want gone)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=blacklist --remove-entry=x.x.x.x`